# How to remove an element above the navbar without moving the content?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, navbar

I built this so far with w3.css:

```js
 $(function() {

  $(window).scroll(function() {
    var x = $(window).scrollTop();
    var h = $("#navi").height();
    var z = $("#topper").height();

    if (x >= z) {
      //$("#header").hide();
      $("#navi").addClass("w3-top");
      $("#content").css("margin-top", h);
    } else {
      //$("#header").show();
      $("#navi").removeClass("w3-top");
      $("#content").css("margin-top", 0);
    }

  });

});
```

```html
<head>
 <title></title>
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/4/w3.css">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons">
</head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<body>

 <header class="w3-container" id="topper">
  <span>HEADER HEADER HEADER</span>
 </header>
  
 <div class="" id="navi">
  <div class="w3-bar w3-pink">
   <span class="w3-bar-item" style="display: none; width:">SOLI</span>
   <div class="w3-dropdown-hover">
    <button class="w3-button w3-mobile">1</button>
    <div class="w3-dropdown-content w3-bar-block w3-card-4">
     <a href="#" class="w3-bar-item w3-button" style="width:">1a</a>
     <a href="#" class="w3-bar-item w3-button" style="width:">1b</a>
     <a href="#" class="w3-bar-item w3-button" style="width:">1c</a>
     <a href="#" class="w3-bar-item w3-button" style="width:">1d</a>
    </div>
   </div>
   <div class="w3-dropdown-hover" id="navi">
    <button class="w3-button">2</button>
    <div class="w3-dropdown-content w3-bar-block w3-card-4">
     <a href="#" class="w3-bar-item w3-button" style="width:">2a</a>
     <a href="#" class="w3-bar-item w3-button" style="width:">2b</a>
     <a href="#" class="w3-bar-item w3-button" style="width:">2c</a>
     <a href="#" class="w3-bar-item w3-button" style="width:">2d</a>
     <a href="#" class="w3-bar-item w3-button" style="width:">2e</a>
     <a href="#" class="w3-bar-item w3-button" style="width:">2f</a>
    </div>
   </div>
   <a href="#" class="w3-bar-item w3-button" style="width:">3</a>
   <a href="#" class="w3-bar-item w3-button" style="width:">4</a>
   <a href="#" class="w3-bar-item w3-button" style="width:">5</a>
   <a href="#" class="w3-bar-item w3-button w3-right" style="width:">6</a>
  </div>
 </div>

 <div class="" id="content">
  <img src="https://assets.pixolum.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2016/10/focus-stacking-scharfe-bilder-1.jpg">
  <img src="https://assets.pixolum.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2016/10/focus-stacking-scharfe-bilder-1.jpg">
  <img src="https://assets.pixolum.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2016/10/focus-stacking-scharfe-bilder-1.jpg">
 </div>
</body>
```

But the problem is whenever I scroll down the content (eagle pictures) scolls, too, and hides behind the navbar...
I want the site to behave similar like [this page](https://www.w3schools.com/html/default.asp) when I scoll down.
Does anyone know what to do here? :)

**sorry:** ddddddd dddddddddddddddddd dddddddddddddddd ddddddddddddddddddddddddddd dddddd

Comment: Can you please clarify "scroll down the content (eagle pictures) scrolls, too"? The navigation seems to function identical to w3schools.

Comment: Navigation works fine! It's the 1st picture that is a bit cut off at its top as soon as #topper (the header) disappears

Comment: I want that as soon as the header disappears, the navigation bar gets the class "w3-top" so that it's always at the top of the screen und the content shall begin direct under the navbar, not behind it

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to tell what you want, but I think this is it. You need to add background through `CSS` and use `fixed` property on it.

```js
$(function() {

  $(window).scroll(function() {
    var x = $(window).scrollTop();
    var h = $("#navi").height();
    var z = $("#topper").height();

    if (x >= z) {
      //$("#header").hide();
      $("#navi").addClass("w3-top");
      $("#content").css("margin-top", h);
    } else {
      //$("#header").show();
      $("#navi").removeClass("w3-top");
      $("#content").css("margin-top", 0);
    }

  });

});
```

```html
<head>
 <title></title>
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/4/w3.css">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons">
</head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<body style='background: url(https://assets.pixolum.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2016/10/focus-stacking-scharfe-bilder-1.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed; background-size: cover; height: 200em;'>

 <header class="w3-container" id="topper">
  <span>HEADER HEADER HEADER</span>
 </header>
  
 <div class="" id="navi">
  <div class="w3-bar w3-pink">
   <span class="w3-bar-item" style="display: none; width:">SOLI</span>
   <div class="w3-dropdown-hover">
    <button class="w3-button w3-mobile">1</button>
    <div class="w3-dropdown-content w3-bar-block w3-card-4">
     <a href="#" class="w3-bar-item w3-button" style="width:">1a</a>
     <a href="#" class="w3-bar-item w3-button" style="width:">1b</a>
     <a href="#" class="w3-bar-item w3-button" style="width:">1c</a>
     <a href="#" class="w3-bar-item w3-button" style="width:">1d</a>
    </div>
   </div>
   <div class="w3-dropdown-hover" id="navi">
    <button class="w3-button">2</button>
    <div class="w3-dropdown-content w3-bar-block w3-card-4">
     <a href="#" class="w3-bar-item w3-button" style="width:">2a</a>
     <a href="#" class="w3-bar-item w3-button" style="width:">2b</a>
     <a href="#" class="w3-bar-item w3-button" style="width:">2c</a>
     <a href="#" class="w3-bar-item w3-button" style="width:">2d</a>
     <a href="#" class="w3-bar-item w3-button" style="width:">2e</a>
     <a href="#" class="w3-bar-item w3-button" style="width:">2f</a>
    </div>
   </div>
   <a href="#" class="w3-bar-item w3-button" style="width:">3</a>
   <a href="#" class="w3-bar-item w3-button" style="width:">4</a>
   <a href="#" class="w3-bar-item w3-button" style="width:">5</a>
   <a href="#" class="w3-bar-item w3-button w3-right" style="width:">6</a>
  </div>
 </div>


</body>
```

Comment: Yeah. Without any further clarification, I was assuming this is what he is looking for as well.

Comment: @escapesequence It's really hard to tell what he want's, but we can only hope this is it, so others don't waste time on this anymore.

Comment: sorry for my lack of clarity! I didn't mean to have a background but the content should be placed directly under the navbar as soon as the header disappears (through jQuery) and should not be behind the navbar (as it is right now)

Comment: @ThomasK It's still hard to understand what you want. Do you want content to be `fixed` to your navbar, so it scrolls with your navbar ?

Comment: @Zvezdas1989 look at w3: https://www.w3schools.com/html/default.asp
- first you see the header, then the navbar and then the content. 
- If you scoll down now the navbar and the content move up parallel (as it should when you scroll down) but at the same thime the header disappears. 
- When you scroll on the navbar stays on top of the screen and the content keeps scrolling normally

that's what I would like to build, too.

Comment: @ThomasK As far as I can tell your original does just that.

Comment: @Zvezdas1989 not exactly since the content is b it cut off at its top/ it's a bit behind the navbar - not placed fully under it